# change div class based on data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, iframe

I have an iframe and 2 css codes, one for landscape one for portrait, but that is not for the device portrait or landscape more for the content that is loaded in the iframe ex. games that are designed in landscape mode vs games designed in portrait mode.

I have 2 sets of css they work good if I enable them however I want to add in the same button since is 1 universal div that triggers the game popup iframe to load the iframe css accordignly to some data attribute example

```
<a href="mygamelink" target="iframe" data="portrait">click me to play</a>
```

if I click the above link iframe should load/change iframes class ... since i have css for that class

```
<a href="mygamelink" target="iframe" data="landscape">click me to play</a>
```

if I click the above link iframe should load/change iframes class ... since I have css for that class

```
<iframe class="portrait/landscape" name="iframe"></a>
```

I know is possible with jquery I think any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If the iframe is on the same domain as the parent page, you should be able to access the iframe's content body and you could put a class on the `body` which you could drive your css off of.  Though I have to ask.  You said you have two css, which makes me suspect that you are possibly not using media queries?  Portrait vs Landscape, really all you are concerned with is the window width.

Comment: not using media cause there are 100 types of devices tablets and other ratios .. this way is universal fitting all with no media specific

Comment: And no the iframe content is not on same page as the iframe element itself, im using a different location on another server that delivers content much faster then my websites server. so there is that :-s

Comment: and im not using media because is not for device orientation, but for the content that is inside the iframe, they are landscape developed or portrait developed, as i said above think games, some are developed to fit portrait some landscape the iframe css code wraps around the content perfect, similar to facebook messenger, however my issue was that i could only had 1 css ... the bellow answers i think solved my problem. ... anyway this was not a media and (orientation:??) issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/560/)**.

The links should have a `data-*` attributes like :

```
<a href="mygamelink" target="iframe" data-format="portrait" class="iframe_link">click me to play</a>
<a href="mygamelink" target="iframe" data-format="landscape" class="iframe_link">click me to play</a>
```

Then add a click event on the hrefs by common attribute (class `iframe_link` in my example ) :

```
$('.iframe_link').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $('[name="iframe"]').attr('class', ( $(this).data('format') ));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Links

```
<a id="first-link" href="mygamelink" target="iframe" data-display="portrait">click me to play</a>
<a id="second-link" href="mygamelink" target="iframe" data-display="landscape">click me to play</a>
```

Iframe

```
<iframe id="my-iframe" class="portrait/landscape" name="iframe"></a>
```

Set class for iframe with jQuery:

```
var display = $("#first-link").data("display");
if(display === "portrait") {
    $("#my-iframe").addClass("portrait");
} else {
    $("#my-iframe").addClass("landscape");
}
```

Same for second link or use a class to group them.